# On Euler totient function sum

Tags: number-theory, summation, analytic-number-theory, totient-function

Let $q$ an arbitrary integer. Is there any chance of getting a bound like $$\underset{d\mid q}{\sum}\frac{1}{\phi\left(q/d\right)^{2}}\ll\frac{1}{\phi\left(q\right)^{2}}?$$

Comment: By $a \ll b$, you mean "There is a $C$ such that $a \leqslant C\cdot b$"?

Comment: Doesn't $\phi(q)\to \infty$ as $q\to\infty$, while the LHS is at least $1$?

Comment: How did your question arise?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understand the question, but if this helps at all:
$$\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{1}{\phi(n/d)^2}=\prod_{p\mid n}(1+\frac{1}{\phi(p)^2}+\frac{1}{\phi(p^2)^2}+\frac{1}{\phi(p^3)^2}...+\frac{1}{\phi(p^{v_p(n)})^2})$$
$$=\prod_{p\mid n}(1+\frac{1}{(p-1)^2}(1+\frac{1}{p^2}+\frac{1}{p^4}+..\frac{1}{p^{2(v_p(n)-1)}}))$$
$$=\prod_{p\mid n}(1+\frac{1-p^{-2v_p(n)}}{(p-1)^2(1-p^{-2})})$$

$$\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{1}{\phi(n/d)^2}<\prod_{p}(1+\frac{1}{(p-1)^2(1-p^{-2})})<3.4$$